# Bind9 : Host dns.lan not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dns

I am currently trying to set up a DNS (dns.lan) on my virtual machine.

I have a gateway machine (IP: 192.168.1.1) and I have a DNS machine (192.168.1.5)

I always have the same error when I type `host dns.lan` which is "Host dns.lan not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)". Where do the error come from ?

/etc/resolve.conf:

```
...
nameserver 192.168.1.5
domain dns.lan
search dns.lan
```

/etc/hostname:

```
DNS
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 DNS
192.168.1.5 DNS.dns.lan DNS
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.options:

```
...
forwarders {
    89.2.0.1;
    192.168.1.1;
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
}
...
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.local:

```
zone "bsasr.lan" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.dns.lan";
}
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bin/zones/db.192";
}
```

To avoid mistakes, here is a screenshot of my /etc/bind/zones/db.dns.lan:
[db.bsasr.lan screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIi6E.png)

Same for /etc/bind/zones/db.192:

[db.192 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX9AT.png)

Here are the errors:

```
>host dns.lan
Host dns.lan not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

>nslookup dns.lan
Server: 89.2.0.1
Address: 89.2.0.1#53

server can't find dns.lan: NXDOMAIN
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun fact: Your primary DNS resolving server is actually *not* your 192.168.1.5 box.  That's why an `nslookup` without specifying the DNS server to query is failing.

Your primary query point is 89.2.0.1 apparently, which is the `server` field of the `nslookup` response, which doesn't have the zone defined in it.  So, you need to point your `resolv.conf` and/or your network settings (if using Network Manager) to start with 192.168.1.5 first then go to other servers as failover.

If you do `nslookup bsasr.lan 192.168.1.5` you should get an actual DNS resolve, not an NXDOMAIN.  Make sure your `/etc/resolv.conf` is actually staying the same as well - if you're using network manager it might not be the same as you expect, and the DNS server has to be wherever you're using `nslookup`, not the `bind9` server system itself.

I strongly also suggest you use `dig` to test with, so you can do `dig +short @192.168.1.5 A [ADDRESS]` (replacing `[ADDRESS]` accordingly) for what you're trying to test with; `dig` works nicely with `bind9`.

Comment: Thank you very much... I works like a charm!! I have edited the order of resolve.conf and it works now, thank you very much!!